# Animate the removal of layout_centerHorizontal

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I have a view that is centered vertically. I want to be remove the `layout_centerHorizontal` attribute so that it will rise to the top of the view, but I want to animate that transition.

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/center_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="65sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >
    ...
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

java

```
 private void showSplits(){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) centerBox.getLayoutParams();
    lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    centerBox.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //but I want to animate this instead...
}
```

Comment: don't use `sp` for margin :)

Comment: haha, normally I wouldn't. But, I want the margin to sort of line up with a TextView that's pinned to the top, so I decided to make an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Animate Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

In java Function Code:

```
private void showSplits(){
centerBox.startAnimation(animFadein);
}
```

In Create View Code:

```
OnCreate{
// load the animation
animMoveIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
R.anim.animate);
animMoveIn.setAnimationListener(this);
}
```

And you should implement AnimationListener.